# JavaScript validate size for multiple files

Tags: javascript

Ok this is very confusing question, only for experts.

I have plugin which dynamically creates input fields for contact form.

so in many input fields for uploading files. I have  defined **onchange** event something like this.

```
onchange=" var len = $(\'[type=file]\').length  ;  for(i=0; i < len; ++i){ if($(\'[type=file]\')[i].files[0].size > 15000000 ){ $(\'.inputDugme\').attr(\'disabled\',\'disabled\'); alert(\'Maksimalna dozvoljena veličina fajla je 15mb\')}else{$(\'.inputDugme\').removeAttr(\'disabled\',\'disabled\');}}"
```

I try on click event to check all input fields, and if are bigger than 15mb then disable the submit button.

I count number of input fields

```
$(\'[type=file]\').length
```

problem is because another input field doesn't have file, I will get error in **JavaScript**, since I have written this line

```
if($(\'[type=file]\')[i].files[0].size > 15000000 )
```

I will have undefined index, because second file for  input field isn't selected.

Help is needed.Any ideas?

Comment: On change, check for changed input only, not every one. And please don't use inline html event handlers, it's kind of a bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add the filesizes of the added files together, something like this
*(using jQuery, but it's the same without it)*

```
var inputs = $('input[type="file"]')

inputs.on('change', function() {
    var size = 0;

    inputs.each(function() {            // iterate over all inputs
        $.each(this.files, function() { // iterate over all available files
            size += this.size;          // add up the filesizes
        });
    });

    if (size > 15000000) {
        alert('Too much data !');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tdka861/)

Comment: yes i need something like this but to check each file size, and if bouth files are smaller than 15 remove disable attr for button

Answer (score 0):

instead of simply selecting all file inputs, `$(\'[type=file]\')`, filter those that have files:

```
$('[type=file]').filter(function(fl){
  return this.value;
})
```

convert this to a string and use this.